# Copy files found by findstr?

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, directory, findstr

Im trying to copy files I found with findstr to another folder.
This is what I made that lists all the files I want to be copied

```
dir * /a /b  |findstr ^FALSE[0-9][0-9]\.txt$
```

How can I redirect this list to a copy command? Im trying not to use a batch file.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Del` command is what you intended to use, and not the `Dir` command? I ask, because once you've deleted something, it is impossible to copy it! In addition, why would you use a `*` glob, instead of something more like, `FALSE*.txt`, which would no doubt be more efficient. Also `[0-9][0-9]`, would be better as `[0123456789][0123456789]`, because you probably don't want to match characters like `¹`, `²`, and `³`. Finally, to do what you need, I would suggest you use that command in a [tag:for-loop]. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: yeah sorry copied the wrong one, it was dir instead of delete

Comment: Given your correction, _(thanks)_, here's an example for you: `For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "FALSE*.txt" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "^FALSE[0123456789][0123456789]\.txt$"') Do @Copy /Y "%G" "A:\nother\Folder"`

Comment: You need to put the search string in between `""` to not lose the `^`-sign, which also constitutes the escape character for `cmd.exe`…

Comment: hm,. thanks but your given code does not seem to work, it tells me file not found

Comment: I provided only an example based upon the poor information you have provided. If you want specific help with sonmething, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64859587/edit) facility, and update your post to provide a [mcve] of your properly formatted code, and to meet the guidelines explained under [ask], and its associated links. To clarify, there is nothing wrong with the [[tag:windows]] [[tag:cmd]] code I have offered, the issue is with your implementation of it, or your provided information.

Comment: BTW, as you're now logged back in, please note that if you've used the incorrect tags, i.e. this is being run in a batch file, _(a file with a `.cmd`, or `.bat` extension)_, you will need to replace all instances of `%G` with `%%G`!

Comment: Also if you wanted to `delete`, instead of `copy`, there's absolutely no reason why you shouldn't have modified your question's title, and body, either. `For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B /A:-D "FALSE*.txt" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "^FALSE[0123456789][0123456789]\.txt$"') Do @Del /A /F "%G"`.

Comment: im just wondering, what the "FALSE*.txt" after the /A:-D flag does do?

Comment: It is filtering all files in the current directory whose basename begins with the case insensitive string `FALSE` and which has an extension beginning with the case insensitive string `.txt`. You provided a `findstr` command which matches filenames beginning with the case sensitive string `FALSE`, is followed by two characters in the range `0-9`, and which ends with the case sensitive string `.txt`. That means, as I have already explained, it is quicker to filter all files in the current directory, `*`, so that less are then piped to the `findstr.exe` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this is easier in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. When you are confident that the correct files willbe copied to the correct location, remove the `-WhatIf` from `Copy-Item`.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t' -Filter 'FALSE*.txt' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^FALSE[0-9]{2}\.txt$' } |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\the\other\place' -WhatIf }
```

If this is only in a command shell, you could use:

```
gci -File 'C:\src\t\FALSE*.txt'|?{$_.Name -match '^FALSE[0-9]{2}\.txt$'}|%{ Copy-Item $_.FullName 'C:\the\other\place' -WhatIf }
```

Comment: Yes. `Copy-Item` could be changed to `Remove-Item` with appropriate parameters.